# How to use google translate api for Webview in Android application?

Tags: android, webview, google-translate

How to use google translate api for translate the content of the website inside the  android Webview.

### Explanation

I am showing the webpage in my application throw webview. I want to translate the web page contents based on the Locale of the android device

Please any one tell is it possible or not 
Yes means how to do that

Answer (score 0):

The API is now for paying developers only (sad, but inevitable), but it is available. See here: https://developers.google.com/translate/